# How can we modify component state as well when an action is dispatched?

Tags: reactjs, redux

`

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Chart from '../components/chart.js';
import GoogleMap from '../containers/googlemap';
import {removeCityMap} from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import AttributeSelector from './attributeselector'

class WeatherBoard extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData1: []
        }
    }
    weatherAttrMapper(attrName){
        //Setting the state which is based on the data received from action dispatched.
        this.setState({
            chartData1:this.props.weather[0].list.map(weather => weather.main[attrName])
        })
    }
    renderMapList(cityData){
        //Based on the weather prop received when action is dispached I want to set the state before rendering my <chart> element.
        this.weatherAttrMapper('temp');
        return(
            <tr key = {cityName}>
                <td><Chart data = {this.state.chartData1} color = "red" units="K"/></td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <table className="table table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.weather.map(this.renderMapList.bind(this))} 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}
//This is the weather state coming from my reducer which is being used here.
function mapStateToProps({ weather }) {
    return { weather };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ removeCityMap }, dispatch);
}
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(WeatherBoard);
```

`I have a doubt regarding state management.

Problem statement: I have a container abc.JS file which is mapped to redux state by mapStateToProps. 
I have a action handler on button click which fetches data from API. When my actionhandler is dispatched it hits my render method in abc.js. Now my ask is I am maintaining state in abc.js as well which is also being used in render method and this need to be modified when action is dispatched. So how can I setstate my abc.js state which could also be rendered.

I have also added the exact code snippet of my abc.js. So basically I enter my render method when action is dispatched and I here I need to setstate somehow.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to use a state manager if you will also manage state within a component? Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of the the state manager

Comment: I have added the exact snippet for reference. basically this local state as well is also needed by some another dropdown change event happening on the page. Please suggest if my approach is wrong.

Comment: It does not matter really where your state is needed, a state manager should be enough to serve that purpose. For instance, based on how you are using the chart data that comes in as props mapped by redux, is quite redundant. I fail to see it's usefulness. It seems this would have worked perfectly fine with just the mapped state from redux, with less complexity, even.

Comment: I mean, think about it: You take a state and pass it to props and then pass it to state! Doesn't sound right, does it?

Comment: Let me tell this scenario, here I am receiving the weather information in container state which contains temp, pressure, humidity. I am rendering the charts from this data by setting it in this.state.chartData1 based on temp. Now suppose I have a dropdown above chart having options temp,pressure,humidity with temp currently selected. Now on dropdown change to humidity or pressure my redux state is not changing but I will only change my component state  this.state.chartData1 and only this chart will be re rendered considering I have other charts as well on my page. Have a thought on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you need to do, if you just need to dispatch an action and set the state "at the same time" then something like this would work:

```
...
  handleOnClick = () => {
    this.props.actions.myAction();
    this.setState({ myStateField: "myNewValue" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>MyContainer</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

If instead you need to dispatch an action then based on how the state in your manager is updated you need to also update the state, then you can use a simple lifecycle method like `componentWillReceiveProps` there you can read the new props and even compare the to the old props and act upon it, meaning that based on that you can then update your state. Let me know if this helps otherwise I can update my answer ;)

EDIT:

After reading your comment, this is what you want to do:

```
...
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // In here you can also use this.props to compare the current props
  // to the new ones and do something about it
  this.setState({ myStateField: nextProps.propFromRedux });
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I have added the exact snippet. The state which I received from redux I need to use in my setstate and use this state in rendering itself.

Comment: I edited my answer @ankitgupta , let me know how that goes and if it works out make sure to mark this question as resolved ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if you are dependent on state value which is being set from using props. Use componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle hook to setState . it will do the job. It gets triggered whenever there is a props change in update phase

Answer (score 0):

before dispatching your action you can just say this.setState{} and it will modify your component state and once the action dispatches it again cause a re-render because this action may change some of the store's state.